# Show button only in longer pages with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

How should I specify CSS (preferebly only CSS, or alternatively CSS + JS) for the "to top" button in the page, so that the button is visible only if the content of the page is longer than the height of the user's screen. I do not want to have the button visible if the content of the specific page fits in well in the single screen in the specific device (without the necessity to scroll it). The code for the button is simple:

```
<a href="#top" class="arrow-top">Top</a>
```

Comment: This was an answer of mine to a similar question, but using javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23110156/2394259

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get div to show/hide when scrolling for a "back to top" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109963/get-div-to-show-hide-when-scrolling-for-a-back-to-top-link)

Comment: No my question is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 100) {
$('.arrow-top').fadeIn();
} else {
 $('.arrow-top').fadeOut();
}
});
```

```css
body{
height: 2000px;
}

.arrow-top{
display: none;
position: fixed;
bottom: 2px; 
right: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background: #222;
color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a class="arrow-top" href="">Top</a>
</body>
```

Use jquery scroll function to show or hide an element on scroll. Get reference from the below code.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 100) {
$('.arrow-top').fadeIn();
} else {
 $('.arrow-top').fadeOut();
}
});
```

Set `display: none;` for `.arrow-top` initially in your css. and it will only show if you scroll the document below 100px. You can adjust the scroll height as per your requirements.

**Edit : Updated with snippet.**

Hope this help.

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri Has anyone noticed that clicking on `Top` completely disables scrolling. ^_^ Change `href=""` to `href="#"`. :)

Comment: Obviously, it will because Its just for reference as there were no jquery to compliment the question.

Comment: and this is quite obvious that @Annabelle will add some click function to that anchor in future.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if( $(window).height()<$("body").height()){
  $(".arrow-top").show();
}
```

```css
.arrow-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6%;
    right: 1.5%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: transparent;
    border: 3px solid #e82a62;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#e82a62;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
  <p>Bala</p>
</div>
<a href="#top" style="display:none;" class="arrow-top">^</a>
```